# how to set the timeout value in AFImageRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I having problem with downloading array of images from server, if i have 100 images on server means i should download all images using "AFImageRequestOperation", while downloading process some images are downloaded successfully but many images are failed to download because of "TimeOut" error from server,i facing Timeout issue with large size image(3.mb),

i using follwing way to downloading images:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURLString];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUserDefaultKeyUsername]
                                      password:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUserDefaultKeyPassword]];

for( int i = 0; i < [self.downloadImageList count]; i++ ) {

    NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self.downloadImageList objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                            path:@"/xxx/yyyyyyyyyy/getImage"
                                                                      parameters:nil
                                                       constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

                                                           [formData appendPartWithFormData:[filename dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                                       name:kFormNameFile];

                                                       }];

    AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [requestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

        [self updateSyncClientUIDelegateProgress:(totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead) andLabel:@"Downloading Images"];
    }];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        if( [[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[[operation request] URL]] ) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImage *image = responseObject;
                NSLog(@"Downloading  image %@",image);

                [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[syncedImagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
            });

        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if( [[operation response] statusCode] == 404 ) {
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"failure BLOCK %@",error);
        NSLog(@"failure error code %ld",(long)[error code]);



        if( [error code] != NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData ) {

            [self cancelSyncFromFailure];
        }

    }];
```

Please help me to fix this timeout issue while downloading large iamges

Answer (score 1):

NOW HERE IS THE SOLUTION I AM USING AND WORKING FINE.FIRSTLY IT WAS ALSO SENDING ME THE "**REQUEST TIMEOUT**" MESSAGE BUT NOT NOW.TRY THIS

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:10000];

AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [requestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

     ...... YOUR CODE
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You set TimeOut Request Time is more a below code.

```
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:50];
```

Comment: still facing the same issue, actually im getting  an error from server  Error:  Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x12830130 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxxx.com/yyyy/httpbroker/getImage, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxx.com/yyyyy/httpbroker/getImage, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0xe351d60 "The request timed out."}     failure error code -1001